# Does Kabalah require us to follow the Atkins Diet?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

During *sholas sedudos* we say אתקינו סעודתא, a remez to the Atkins Diet.  It includes descriptions like "זעיר אנפין" -- make your face smaller (thinner), and even instructions about "וַחֲקַל תַּפּוּחִין קַדִּישִׁין" -- "holy (low carb) potatoes".

Is this merely a segulah or does Kabalah actually require us to follow the Atkins Diet?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Isn't just a 'תפוח' an apple? 'תפוח אדמה' is a potato.

Comment: @Aeelnpprsu While that is true in modern Hebrew, in rabbinic hebrew תפוח by itself probably actually means _orange_ or some other citrus. In any event, this is just Purim Torah so bad translations are actually encouraged.

Comment: I would argue that תפוח אדמה is the Modern Hebrew translation.  Since חֲקַל means field, חֲקַל תַּפּוּחִין would mean "apple of the field", very similar to תפוח אדמה.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On days we say Hallel, just before reciting it, we praise Hashem for making us fat.

Baruch Atta Hashem, Ham'varech et amo yisrael, ba-sha-mein...

So we know fat is praised.

Comment: bashalom we say, where is written ba-sha-mein?

Comment: @havarka The end of bashalom often gets swallowed up in the congregation's amen.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm no expert on the exact particulars of the Atkins, but the Mishna (*braysa?*) in Avos ([6:4](http://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.6?lang=he-en&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all)) gives us a very, very strict diet:

> פת במלח תאכל ומים במשורה תשתה
>
> [E]at bread with salt and drink a small amount of water

(*Sefaria's translation*)

כך היא דרכה של תורה -- This is the way of the Torah!!